# BMesh Grid Fill doesn't work on closed edge loop

Tags: python, scripting, bmesh

I've been trying to automate the task of deleting the ngon cap on the end of a cylinder and replacing it with quads using the [Grid Fill](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html#grid-fill) tool.

Something similar to this:
[image: Grid fill]

I'm using this script:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

# Get the active mesh
me = bpy.context.object.data


# Get a BMesh representation
bm = bmesh.new()   # create an empty BMesh
bm.from_mesh(me)   # fill it in from a Mesh

# Loop through all the faces deleting the ngons.
for f in bm.faces:
    if len(f.verts) > 4:
        bmesh.ops.delete(bm, geom=[f], context=5)

        # After each ngon is deleted, find the non-manifold edges and fill using grid fill.
        edges = []
        for e in bm.edges:
            if not e.is_manifold:
                edges.append(e)
        bmesh.ops.grid_fill(bm, edges=edges)

# Finish up, write the bmesh back to the mesh
bm.to_mesh(me)
bm.free()  # free and prevent further access
```

But whenever I run the script with a default cylinder I get the fallowing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bmesh.py", line 22, in <module>
RuntimeError: bmesh operator: Select two edge loops
```

The BMesh Grid Fill operator seems to be expecting two opposite edge loops, but the edit mode Grid Fill tool can accept one connected edge loop (as you can see in the image above). So there seems to be an inconsistency between the two.

Am I missing something? Or should I report this as a bug?

Comment: As usual, I think the operator in the UI does more than bmesh.ops.grid_fill() alone, did you try adding a second empty set of edges? Or a bit hacky, split your edge selection in two and give that to the operator.

Comment: What I ended up doing is dividing the total number of edges by 4, then selecting two opposite sets of edges of that size. bmesh.ops.grid_fill() seems to work just fine when it gets two seperate edge loops.